# Bootstrap Shortcode for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, shortcode

I'm using this shortcode to return 1/3 columns in wordpress. It works well, but I would like to return two columns when at a certain break point. What am I missing here? When on mobile it does stack the elements one on top of another which I want, it just doesn't go down to two.

```
function one_third($atts, $content = null) {
    return '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
}
```

[Basic idea of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwYPm.jpg)

```
.site-content {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-justify-content: flex-start;

    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    flex-align-content: stretch;

    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
```

}

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. How would you expect three columns to go down to two?

Comment: When they hit say the 'tablet' break point, it would go from three items down to two, then when on mobile they are stacked in one column

Comment: So you're trying to hide one of the columns?

Comment: I'm trying to get them to wrap under each other if that makes sense, so the third item all the way to the right would wrap underneath when on a smaller device to make two columns and so forth

Comment: First, we need to stop using columns since using bootstrap there are 12 columns no matter the size of the viewport. What I believe you are asking, on tablet, you want the first two elements to be 50 percent of the viewport and the third to be 100 percent of the viewport. So you have two elements stacked above the last one. Is this correct?

Comment: On tablet I just want my items to be two in a row stacked

Comment: Can you add a quick image of what you're looking for? I'm not sure it's very clear - since the last comment would suggest you could add `col-sm-6` to your div.

Comment: Just added a picture

Comment: Have you tried using `col-sm-6`? That seems like what you want. Or do you want them to be pushed from the left? So they are in the center of the tablet?

Comment: I added col-sm-6 to the classes but it didn't seem to do anything

Comment: `col-sm-6` will make each of the columns 6 columns wide from 576px and above. What are you seeing? Are the columns in a flex parent?

Comment: They stay at 3 across until mobile when the items stack on top of each other, I will post the parent CSS

Comment: First of all, which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm not I just found this shortcode and it worked. I am using wordpress if that helps. I tried to link up bootstrap in my header.php file but didn't seem to work..

Comment: Well, this is probably why it's not working. `col-*` classes are specific to bootstrap. Saying "WordPress" doesn't help either. Does your theme use Bootstrap. How did you try to include Bootstrap in your `header.php`

Comment: I linked it in the <head> of the header.php with my other style sheets

Comment: So, that should work, but are your `col-*` wrapped in a flex parent? Side note: a better way to include CSS/JS is to use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) in your functions.php.

Comment: Ugh I cannot seem to get it to work. I just tried the wp_enqueue way

Comment: They aren't wrapped in a flex parent but my site-content has the attribute display:flex

Comment: That's the problem. In order for what you have to work, that HTML markup you have needs to be in a flex parent - a direct parent. And you need to have Bootstrap loaded.

Comment: thanks a lot! you really helped